# Is there a "tree-based-correlation" for tree-based algorithms?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, correlation

Although correlated features are not a big issue when training tree-based models, they spoil model explainability. When several features correlate, sometimes they may be picked at random. Then their individual feature importance are lower than if it were a single feature - "common" importance is divided within the correlated group.

Apparently the same issue applies to permutation importance method, as stated in the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html#):

> When two features are correlated and one of the features is permuted, the model will still have access to the feature through its correlated feature. This will result in a lower importance value for both features, where they might actually be important.

As trees are non-linear models, then this "correlation" property observed in them should be also non-linear (or piecewise-linear), and usual methods of finding linear correlation beforehand may be misleading.

Is there a way to calculate such property, given sklearn DecisionTree, for example?

Or there is no such tree-specifics and linear correlation should work well?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question: it's true that the correlation between two features might be different in different nodes since it applies to different subsets of data, but as far as I know at any particular node it's the usual linear correlation which applies. As far as I'm aware there's no tree-specific correlation (and I'm not sure how this would work).

Comment: @Erwan Let's say, if we build a tree and each time we make a split, we track features which are close to producing the best split. Then we check if there are common pairs of features which "compete" frequently each split. So they can have this non-linear relationship, but probably to not have much of linear correlation.

Comment: just to be on the same page, first it's important to distinguish two things: 2 features can be correlated together, and 2 features can both be correlated with the target variable. In the first case the 2 features might not correlate with the target; in the 2nd case the 2 features might not correlate with each other. 2 features "compete" with each other if they are both correlated with the target. If 2 features *frequently* compete with each other, it's very likely that they also correlate with each other. I think it would be difficult to find a case where 2 features frequently ...

Comment: ... compete with each other but which are not linearly correlated.